# How can I dynamically create a service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically instantiate services during runtime given a string name (i.e. reflection). Something like:

```
let myService = new window[myClassName](myParams);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
let myService = Object.create(window[myClassName].prototype);
myService.constructor.apply(myService, myParams);
```

I have looked at `Injector` class, but it requires a type, instead of a string ( https://angular.io/api/core/Injector ) .

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: what about new MyService(params) ???

Comment: That won't work. I am trying to instantiate a class using just the name of the class passed into the method as a string.

Comment: Maybe some kind of string-based token would help?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the underlying usecase? This smells like a XY problem to me.

Comment: Classes aren't identified by their names. Function name isn't preserved during minification. This is a XY problem indeed. Please, update the question with information on what your case exactly is, because expected solution is a deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the Injector in combination with strings. It's just a matter of providing your providers in the way you want to use them. 
This is the example on the Angular page: https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#example-1 
`[provide: Square]` is short for `[provide: Square, useClass: Square]` (you can use `useFactory` instead of `useClass` when you want to instantiate the service yourself) You can change the first param (`provide`) by basically any Symbol you want, so also string.
Have a look at this POC I set up https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mg1ezb

Comment: How would you update your code for Angular 8, where `get` is deprecated with `any` type and shows this message `get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T>`?? I have similar case, with multiple tokens based on which I would like to identify the correct service.

Answer (score -3):

You can try

```
instance = new window["yourClassName"]();
```

Comment: Thanks, however I already tried this. I receive the error: "TypeError: window.MyService is not a constructor"